# How to access global variables inside a function having same local variable in python?

Tags: python

```
v=1
def func():
    v=2
    print(v)
def add():
    v=3
    print(v+v)
func()
add()
```

Here I want to get 1 on calling func() and 4 on calling add().How can I get them ??

Comment: You control the variable names. You can just pick better names. You don't need to look for hacky workarounds to an unnecessary problem you've created for yourself.

Comment: I agree with @user2357112supportsMonica you should use different variable names altogether. And if I may add, use variable names that make sense, or in the long run you're gonna forget what your code is doing especially if it is a complex one.

Comment: If you will forgive me, this is a silly thing to ask.  How on earth could you ever expect things to work this way?  If you set `v=2` in a function, then you want `v` to be 2.  There is no context in which what you ask would make sense.

Comment: Please read the information on the tags, for example: [tag:python-requests] *USE ONLY FOR THE PYTHON REQUESTS LIBRARY. Requests is a full-featured Python HTTP library with an easy-to-use, logical API.*. Also read [ask] and review the [tour]

Comment: Maybe the title is just misleading. If I just look at the results you want to have, the easiest way is to just switch the position of the print function to the start of each function. then you get a 1 after calling func() and a 4 after calling add()

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple issues with your code:

- You see to be mixing 'printing' a value and 'returning' a value
- You are re-using a variable name in multiple scopes
- I suspect you don't want to learn about `global v` (see https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/global-keyword)  you instead want to address the first two issues

````
def func():
    v=2
    print(v)
def add():
    v=3
    print(v+v)
func()
add()


# This could be rewritten as:

def func():
    func_value = 2
    return func_value

def add3(value_as_argument):
    return value_as_argument + 3
print(func()) # here we print the returned value from func
print(add3(func())) # here we call add3 on the returned value from func and then we print the value```
````